# How to use SQL Data Reader to check quantity in database?

Tags: sqldatareader

I want to check quantity in the `tblProducts` with the quantity selected by the user. If the user selects more than in `tblProducts`, there will be a pop up message and the quantity will not added. If there is available quantity in `tblProducts`, the user can add the quantity. Do I need to put `SP_UpdateCart` in both if statement?

```
    if (e.CommandName == "DoPlus")//Check quantity here
    {
        string PID = (e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_getUserCartItem", con)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PID", PID);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);

                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        int myQty = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Qty"].ToString());
                        int PQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(dr["PQuantity"].ToString());

                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (myQty < PQuantity)
                            {

                                Int32 updateQty = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString());
                                SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateCart", con)
                                {
                                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                                };
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", updateQty + 1);
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CartPID", PID);
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                                con.Open();
                                Int64 CartID = Convert.ToInt64(myCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                                con.Close();
                                BindProductCart();
                                BindCartNumber();
                            }

                            else if (myQty > PQuantity)//check quantity between tblCart and 
                            tblProducts
                            {
                                Response.Write("<script>alert('Please choose quantity less than 
                                stated!');</script>");
                                Int32 updateQty = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["Qty"].ToString());
                                SqlCommand myCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_UpdateCart", con)
                                {
                                    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                                };
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", updateQty);
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CartPID", PID);
                                myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserID", UserID);
                                con.Open();
                                Int64 CartID = Convert.ToInt64(myCmd.ExecuteScalar());
                                con.Close();
                                BindProductCart();
                                BindCartNumber();

                            }

                        }

                    }
                    dr.Close();
                    
                }con.Close();

            }
           }
           }
```